# Discussing situation before resigning

Tags: resignation, time-management, internal-transfer

I had a look at this [post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/58481/how-to-resign-due-to-incompetence), and it is helpful but i would need some more help, i started in a company and currently on my probation. I have mismanaged everything and i been out of job for many months, since i got this job and i been working (although my progress is slow), i been consumed by a project which is very much time consuming and my other plan which was suppose to start 20 days ago, it delayed and i have to give it on deadline. A lot fall on me being very slow and a programmer who is weak (IMO), till now i have pulled the job but now i feel i am causing business damage (as my deadlines are way overdue), and being only person who has more experience in this field than anyone else, even i feel worn out due to people worked here before me. 
So it come down to the following

1. I am way behind my deadlines (new or old)
2. I fall behind deadline is because of my limited knowledge or rusty skills
3. I have things on my hand which i think i cannot do (but all programmers face something new)
4. My boss think i am good but i don't (i know he is pep talk as he knows i am slow)

In this situation, what should i do, how do i start a conversation with my CTO or manager that can tell him, i am having trouble in work and i think it might be good idea to internally move me to another position, maybe junior? or let me go as i don't want to be fired (as it sounds bad). 
Keeping that in mind, i am thinking i might be jobless again for couple of months, due to my low portfolio and old skills, but TBH i don't know what and how to do.

Comment: Nofel, could you focus this question on a single goal?  Perhaps edit it to work on how you might talk to the CTO about improving your performance or building your confidence.  A blanket "what should I do" or "What advice do you have for me" post doesn't fit our format, but I think this post can be salvaged with a few minor edits.  Hope this helps. See [ask] for details.

Comment: @jmort253 I can edit. But i lost that job after this post and few days later for same reason, anyways.

Comment: Ok. Hope these tips help with future posts.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I am way behind my deadlines (new or old)

A [famous writer](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/1398-i-love-deadlines-i-love-the-whooshing-noise-they-make) once said "I love deadlines. I love the whooshing noise they make as they go by"

Focus on doing the job, and doing it well.  Let your boss worry about the deadlines.

> 2. I fall behind deadline is because of my limited knowledge or rusty skills

So use this as an opportunity to learn more, and become less rusty.  You will *NOT* improve if you resign.

> 3. I have things on my hand which i think i cannot do (but all programmers face something new)

You just answered this yourself.  All programmers face new challenges - it's part of the description of who we are and what we do.  Embrace it, accept it, and be glad that there is always more to learn (and it is impossible to know it all).

> 4. My boss think i am good but i don't (i know he is pep talk as he knows i am slow)

This one's important.  **Your boss believes in you.  Trust that.**

Comment: what would you suggest i do, talk with my boss about shifting me internally or to a junior level and how?

Comment: As I said in my answer, I suggest you **Focus on doing the job, and doing it well**.  There is no need to talk to your boss.

Comment: prior to your msg I already talked with my manager about mismanagement by me and that I am willing to change my position internally, this comes as I am very far far off my deadlines and I didn't wanted to be fired, rather be open. I will be having discussion about it with them, any tips on how to cater and speak so I don't look bad?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried employing any new strategies in how you approach your work? Are you certain that your skills aren't up to par? I always have new stuff that I'm doing for work. It can be a little scary but eventually I get through it (and yeah, sometimes I fall behind on stuff too, but once I get whatever the thing is I usually make up time on the back end.)

You should probably not go directly to the CTO at first, but instead talk to your manager. Ask if they have any suggestions for how you can change your approach. Ask for help. If you take the approach of "I want to be here, but I'm kind of struggling and need some help, and I would much rather be moved to a junior position that I feel more comfortable in than be out of a job." I don't think that your manager would take it any other way. Also, I wouldn't offer the change in position option immediately. Feel it out and see what the response is. Don't offer specific details or outright say that you have "mismanaged everything". That might actually get you fired.

Comment: I can eventually get that what i want to work on, but certain deadline that has way passed danger point and i haven't even worked coz i am stuck with old work as i am struggling with it and even that is very much overdue.

Comment: Either way I think you need to address that before someone else does.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you don't have any of these skills, then how did you get the job in the first place?

And now for whatever reason you are in this demanding new role. Look at it as a potential, nobody including yourself likes to be fired/let go/laid off/ be out of job!

To be honest, I say **work harder!** Learn the new technologies on your own time. Start an hour earlier in the morning and work harder through the night in the first few months to ramp up. Show yourself. You said you are a "Rusty Programmer", I think as long as you are a good programmer (no matter what language you have worked with) you can learn new languages quickly.

**To answer your original question:** If I were you, I would talk to my manager and ask him what are the ways to learn? Mostly *show him you are willing to learn and grow rather than sit and whine*!